# why is text-shadow not showing

Tags: html, css

I want to apply text-shadow property on a heading text but it is not showing

CSS :

```
 .shadow { 
  color: black; 
  font: bold 52px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #fe4902, 
            2px 2px #fe4902, 
            3px 3px #fe4902;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.12s ease-out;
   -moz-transition:    all 0.12s ease-out;
}
.shadow:hover {
   position: relative; 
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.1); 
   -moz-transform:    scale(1.1);
   -ms-transform:     scale(1.1); 
   -o-transform:      scale(1.1); 
   text-shadow: 5px 0px 2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);
 }
```

HTML :

```
 <h1 class='shadow'>Reseller welcome</h1>
```

the scaling is working though

here is the website http://rajafotocopy.com/store

Comment: Firstly, your site is taking a long time to load for me, and secondly, I recommend demonstrating it at https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You have text-shadow: 1px <- left positioning 1px <- top positioning #fe4902

You NEED text-shadow: 1px <- left positioning 1px <- top 2px <- shadow spread positioning #fe4902,

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: even if I delete all of those codes and just leave text-shadow : 5px 0px 2px red; it is still not showing

I tried to inspect element and nothing is telling me what's wrong

Comment: it is working fine in jsfiddle but not in mine https://jsfiddle.net/jcjtp272/

Comment: Does [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/4rhwbpqq/1/) work? ... If not, which browser do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Right click that h1 and you'll see there's no text in h1. The text is 2 levels down in 2 separate `<span>`s, apply the `text-shadow` properties like this:

```
 .shadow .cufon-alt { text-shadow....
```

Notice there is a `<canvas>` in between `.shadow` and `.cufon-alt`, a `<canvas>` can be styled as well but that involves a little JavaScript.

#### UPDATE

It is the `<canvas>` that inhibits the `text-shadow`. I moved the span that contains the text above the `<canvas>` and it works.

[image]

Comment: Oh! cufon. You're the observant one @zer00ne

Comment: but if I do that then not just the shadow, but the scaling isn't working too 

do I need to add z-index as well?

Comment: No, z-index is not needed...I'm sorry I don't fully understand your concern. Have you tried it yet? I have a suspicion that it won't work with that canvas in the middle.

Comment: I got the shadow working but I had to move the span above the canvas. Mr. Fargeat is right, you should place your text elsewhere. H1 would work.

Answer (score 0):

On the website you give, the text is rendered using cufón which prevents CSS properties to be applied to it like they would on a normal text.

See this thread to see how to apply shadows on cufón text: [Textshadow not working on CUFON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145371/textshadow-not-working-on-cufon)

Or just get rid of the cufon and just put the text directly.